# Android lazy list loading from another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a function findLocalEvents() that returns a list of items I want to display in a ListView. Then, in the onCreate() of the activity that populates the listview, I have the following code:

```
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.list_header_view, null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_name);
    title.setText("Events nearby: ");

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.event_list_item,
            findLocalEvents()));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // LIST ITEM IS CLICKED
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(...)
```

What I want to do is display something (e.g. "Loading") to tell the users the list is being populated, and then display all of the items when the findLocalEvents() function finally finishes running. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need threads here for displaying loading message. Following code will give you an idea how to

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Validating Postcode/Zipcode", 
                                    "Please wait...!", true);
startThread();

private void startThread() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    ArrayList<t> arr = NetworkCalls.fetchCategoriesByZipCode();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(categoriesReturned);
            }                   
        }).start(); 
    }
```

and then on runnable you load ListView

```
private Runnable categoriesReturned = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
               //load listview
            }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41879750 that was originally added here". I think it has something to do with not dismissing the dialog box on time? Do you know where in the code I should do this?

Comment: on the other hand, if I don't dismiss it, everything loads fine, but the dialog does not disappear from the screen.